# Autofs home folders from solaris 11

Tags: fedora, solaris, autofs

I'm having trouble since 2 days with autofs.
I have a Solaris 11 Server. 
There I share the folder /export/home with the following command:

share -o rw -d „Freigabe von /export/home“ /export/home

My Client is a Fedora 17.
On Fedora I created the folder /ahome, where all home folders should be mounted with autofs. 
I gave permissions 777 to /ahome.

After that I configured the /etc/auto.master and added

```
/ahome auto.homes
```

Than I created the file /etc/auto.homes

```
read1 192.168.0.3:/export/home/read1
read2 192.168.0.3:/export/home/read2
```

After that I restart autofs with

```
systemctl restart autofs.service
```

Both Users (read1 and read2) exist on both systems with the same UID and GID. 
But when I cd to /ahome/read1 and make an ls on Fedora I get the following error.

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

In /var/log/messages

```
Mar 30 23:43:34 fe-19 pulseaudio[1474]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
Mar 30 23:43:49 fe-19 dbus-daemon[582]: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
Mar 30 23:45:31 fe-19 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit mdmonitor-takeover.service, ignoring: Unit mdmonitor-takeover.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mdmonitor-takeover.service' for details.
Mar 30 23:45:32 fe-19 automount[1100]: umount_autofs_indirect: ask umount returned busy /ahome
Mar 30 23:47:49 fe-19 dbus-daemon[582]: (packagekitd:1508): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Mar 30 23:55:03 fe-19 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit mdmonitor-takeover.service, ignoring: Unit mdmonitor-takeover.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mdmonitor-takeover.service' for details.
Mar 30 23:55:03 fe-19 automount[1933]: umount_autofs_indirect: ask umount returned busy /ahome
```

Please, Can anybody help me?
I start hating autofs

Comment: first of all. Are you able to mount via NFS? I see the share -o but not if you tried to mount it manually.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also have no permissions when I mount the folder with the mount command.

Comment: this might be a bit off. but I remember having issues when mounting NFS v4 between linux and Solaris. I had to force NFS v3 server in Solaris. Maybe you can try that.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris basically assumes that both the client and the server have the same UIDs/GIDs for every user.  What's probably happening is that your 'read1' and 'read2' users don't exist on the Solaris server, so the NFS requests are happening as the NFS anon user.  There are two ways to fix it.

Find the numerical UID of the read1 and read2 users, on the Linux host, then for example, if read1 was UID 101, and read2 was UID 102, you could:

1. You can either chown the /export/home/read1 and /export/home/read2 users to their respective UID, on the Solaris server, via
   `chown -R 101 /export/home/read1`
   `chown -R 102 /export/home/read2`
2. Or you can set the NFS anon user to those UIDs for each user, and individually share each directory.

   `share -o rw -o anon=101 -d „Freigabe von /export/home“ /export/home/read1`

   `share -o rw -o anon=102 -d „Freigabe von /export/home“ /export/home/read2`

However, if you're using ZFS on Solaris 11, which you probably are, you can share these directly in ZFS:

1. Single share for everyone

   `zfs set share=name=homedirs,path=/export/home,prot=nfs,sec=sys,rw rpool/export/home`
2. Individual shares

   `zfs set share=name=read1-homedir,path=/export/home/read1,prot=nfs,sec=sys,rw rpool/export/home/read1`

   `zfs set share=name=read2-homedir,path=/export/home/read2,prot=nfs,sec=sys,rw rpool/export/home/read2`

Doing it this way saves the NFS shares in the metadata of the zpool, and zfs will share those shares anytime that pool is mounted.  Perhaps not totally useful on the rpool, but you have pools made from external disks, it can be handy, especially if you ever need to move disks to a new host.

Comment: "Solaris basically assumes that both the client and the server have the same UIDs/GIDs for every user." You should replace Solaris by nfsv3 in this sentence as this is a NFS v3 and older requirement. NFS v4 user mapping is done differently. You also wrote read1 and read2 users probably do not exist on the Solaris side. Technically, this is not required.

Comment: No, the user's don't need to exist on the solaris server.  If you're using NFSv3, though, you will need to chown the home directories to the right UID and GID, if you want the remote users to be able to read and write to them.  If you're using NFSv4, you can accomplish similar results setting ZFS ACLs for the read1 and read2 users (`chmod A+user:$UID:full_set:fd:allow /export/home/$dir`).  I was unclear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming NFS v3 is used, /export/home/read1 must be owned by read1 and /export/home/read2 by read2.

If you use NFSv4, extra configuration is required for proper mapping between user ids.